# TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '../moduleName.js'. ... has implicit any type

Tags: typescript, .d.ts

I'm seeing this error as I try to import a module which is assigned to an object:

```
// keys.js
export default {
  SHOPIFY_API_KEY: "removed"
  // more keys removed
}

// globalTypings.d.ts
declare module 'nonce' {
 export default function nonce(length?: number): string
}

declare module "keys" {
 export default interface keys {
  SHOPIFY_API_KEY : string
  , SHOPIFY_API_SECRET : string
  , SCOPES : string
  , CLIENT_APP_URL : string
 }
}


// index.ts
import keys from "../keys.js";
// TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '../keys.js'. 'removed/keys.js' implicitly has an 'any' type
```

The nonce module is working. I am only including it in case multiple declarations are a no-no. What is the source of my presumable syntax error above?

**Also tried **

```
import * as keys from "../keys.js";
```

Same error results

```
import {keys} from "../keys.js";
// and default keyword is removed from the interface declaration
```

Same error.

```
// inside the d.ts file
declare module "keys" {
 export interface keys {
  SHOPIFY_API_KEY : string
  , SHOPIFY_API_SECRET : string
  , SCOPES : string
  , CLIENT_APP_URL : string
 }
}

// TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
const keyObj: keys = {
 SHOPIFY_API_KEY : "val"
 , SHOPIFY_API_SECRET : "val"
 , SCOPES : "val"
 , CLIENT_APP_URL : "val"
};
```

Comment: Have you tried using `removed/keys.js` in your module declaration?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I have written a dummy object similar to the one in keys.js, and updated the post with the result

Answer (score 2):

Solved with some refactoring. The key change seemed to be switching keys.js to keys.ts so it could accept the interface from the `global.d.ts` file:

```
// global.d.ts
declare module "keys" {
 interface KeysInterface {
  SHOPIFY_API_KEY : string
  , SHOPIFY_API_SECRET : string
  , SCOPES : string
  , CLIENT_APP_URL : string
 }

 export default KeysInterface;
}

// keys.ts
const keysObj = {
  SHOPIFY_API_KEY: "removed"
  , SHOPIFY_API_SECRET: "removed"
  , SCOPES: "removed"
  , CLIENT_APP_URL: "removed"
};

export default keysObj;


// index.ts
import keys from "../keys";
```